# Why jQuery .submit is not working?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I tried for almost an hour to figure out how to perform some validation before submitting the form. My form is like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script>
 $("#myform").submit(function() {
   alert("it is not working");
   return false;
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myform">
   <input id="foo" value="Change me and press enter"/>
   <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not working in IE, Chrome FF :-(
I must be doing something terribly wrong, but what?

**EDIT**

Working sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function() {
        alert("Now it is def working!");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myform">
<form id="myform">
    <input id="foo" value="Change me and press enter"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your alert text is wrong. When it tells you "it is not working", it actually means "it is working".

Comment: Define "it is not working."  (Which seems to be a poor choice for the alert text, since if the text displays then that means the JavaScript _is_ firing.)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal HA B-)

Comment: We need to find a head question for these too-localised "trying to use a DOM element before it exists" questions.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal ahh but which one?

Comment: Ohh, right.. he's missing the dom ready wrapper

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrap it in the ready function:

```
$(function(){
   $("#myform").submit(function() {
      alert("THIS IS WORKING!!!!!!");
      return false;
   });
});
```

You need to wrap it in the ready function because where your function is now, the DOM element `#myForm` does not exist, so you are attaching the handler to a non existent element.

The ready function waits for the DOM to load and then runs everything inside of the ready fintion.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal added an explanation :-P

Comment: @Neal: Bah, and now my wit is moot!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal its still there ^_^ just in a little lesser of a form :-D